# remove spaces from text file and adding character after specific text

Tags: batch-file

I have a text file where I need to add '1' after the character and removing any spaces between the first two columns. I tried to use the below query but was getting this error

```
201N001466  AD55JGU0604140     VOLKSWAGEN          GOLF S                   BLACK        
201N001437  AF14HFY0604140     BMW                 520D SE AUTO             GREY  
201N001298  AF51NSN0604140     SKODA               FABIA COMFORT 8V
```

this is the format i am looking to add '1' after N and remove any spaces between the first 2 columns.

```
201N1001466AD55JGU0604140     VOLKSWAGEN          GOLF S                   BLACK         
201N1001437AF14HFY0604140     BMW                 520D SE AUTO             GREY               
201N1001298AF51NSN0604140     SKODA               FABIA COMFORT 8V
```

this was my query

```
@echo off
  if [%1]==[] then echo File name missing & goto :EOF
  (for /f "tokens=1" %%a in (%1) do echo %%a) > %~n1_out.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=1,2,*" %%a in (infile.txt) do (
  set a=%%a
  echo !a:~0,4!1!a:~4!%%b %%c
) >>outfile.txt
```

Explanation:

`201N001466  AD55JGU0604140     VOLKSWAGEN          GOLF S               BLACK
 token 1     token 2            token 3 ( token * ).........................`

`echo !a:~0,4!1!a:~4!%%b %%c
!a:~0,4!    first 4 chars from token 1
1           the inserted "1"
!a:~4!      Chars 5 to end of token 1 (counting starts at zero)
%%b         token 2
%%c         token * (Rest of the line)`

Comment: Jut commenting that any `!` characters will cause problems.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a robust method.

This uses a helper batch file called `repl.bat` - download from:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/qidqwztmetbvklt/repl.bat

Place `repl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file or in a folder that is on the path.

```
@echo off
type "file.txt" | repl "(.*?N)(.*?) {1,}(.*)" "$11$2$3" >"newfile.txt"
```

Comment: Where did you put repl.bat?  Were there any error messages on the console?

Comment: in the same folder...i have my file.text, repl.bat, and actual bat file

Comment: Use the sample data you provided and test it to begin with. Extra information after black will be fine.

Comment: Did you call your data file `file.text`?

Answer (score 0):

The way I would go at this is making 7 variables for the numbers that correspond to the space(use what ever you have for the other `strings`(with different names)) like:

```
set num1=201N
set num2=001466
set num3=001437
set num4=001298
set num5=AD55JGU0604140
set num6=AF14HFY0604140
set num7=AF51NSN0604140
```

And when you echo it (if you echo it) with the spaces you would do it like so (first line):

```
echo %num1%%num2%  %num5%  Golf S Black
```

And when you go to add a '1' to the lines you make one more variable and add the line (make a separate variable for each line)

```
set num8=%num1%1%num2%%num5% Golf S Black
```

And just do that for the other two lines.

Hope that helps, Thanks!